# Connect from SSIS to Oracle using ODBC with Kerberos

Tags: oracle, ssis, odbc, kerberos, oracle12c

We have a large SSIS solution with many connection managers pointing to **Oracle**. Provider is ODBC, data sources are set to defined system DSNs. So far we use user names and passwords and everything works fine. Now we want to switch to Kerberos authentication.

I can already successfully query the Oracle database using sqlplus with Windows authentication.

I'm having hard time achieving the same from SSIS using ODBC connection managers.

**Is it possible to reconfigure the ODBC connection managers so they will use Windows authentication? How should be the connection manager configured?**

The question is specifically about ODBC, please avoid answers like "use Attunity".

We use MS SQL Server 2016 Enterprise edition, Oracle 12.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it working, hope it helps someone.

- I created a new DSN
- as User ID I put [OracleUserName]

  - beware the square brackets! Those are necessary
  - the OracleUserName is user name configured on Oracle side (I do not know much about Oracle). The DBA configured the AD account to be able to login as this user.